# Can't Parse link from XML

Tags: php, xml

```
        public function load ( )
    {

        $xml = simplexml_load_file('https://www.google.co.uk/alerts/feeds/03124048891208938389/17727872730326737140');

        foreach ( $xml -> entry as $entry ) 
        {

        $link = $entry -> link;

            echo'<div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                          <div class="caption">
                            <h3>' . $entry -> title . '</h3>
                            <p>' . $entry -> content . '</p>
                            <p>' . $entry -> link . '</p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                </div>';

        } 

    }

}
```

When I try to show "$entry -> link" to match the tag in the xml feed it doesn't show anything.

I don't know what the issue is, I've researched but to no avail.

I've tried assigning $entry -> link to a variable outside of the forreach but that wont crack it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<link>`-tag itself is empty. What you try to access is an attribute.

`<link href="example.com" />`

You can get the attributes using the `attributes()`-function:

```
foreach ($xml->entry as $entry ) {
    //...
    echo '<p>'.$entry->link->attributes()->href.'</p>';
    //...
}
```

More information: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php

Comment: Thank you, that's fixed my issue.